# Import Mac Thunderbird into Windows Outlook?

Tags: email, ms-office, migration, import

I have exported all my data out of Mac Thunderbird, all the emails, contact list and address book entries, as for now I am ketting go off my mac book pro. I have got a new windows laptop that have pre-installed Office 2013 in it. I need to import these files in WIndows Outlook 2013, please can anyone help me with this as I am new to windows environment.

You help will be really appreciated

Comment: If you don't get a good answer, use the edit button to list more about the files the export provided. Also, versions of Thunderbird might me necessary to determine the export format if you don't know that or can provide that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The issue is with the Windows Import, not the Mac Export, so nothing to do with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu cannot directly import Mac Thunderbird mail folders in windows outlook. Firstly convert the thunderbird files to pst format using [Thunderbird to PST Converter](http://thunderbirdtopst.com/) and then follow these steps to import the converted pst file into windows outlook 2013:

Follow these steps to restore, or import, your data into Outlook:

Click the File tab.
In the Open category, click Import.
In the Import and Export Wizard, click Import from another program or file, and then click Next.
Click Outlook Data File (.pst), and then click Next.
Type the path and the name of the .pst file that you want to import, or click Browse to choose the file to import.
Note Under Options, it is recommended that you click Do not import duplicates, unless you want the imported information to replace or duplicate items that are already in Outlook.

Click Next.
Select the folder that you want to import. To import everything in the .pst file, select the top of the hierarchy.
Note The top folder (usually Personal Folders, Outlook Data File or your email address) is selected automatically. Include subfolders is selected by default. All folders under the folder selected will be imported

Click Finish.

Comment: Thanks George for the step-by-step process...and for the link to the tool Thunderbird to Pst Converter. Thumps up for the creators of this application. It was fast and I was able to transfer all my mail data woth accuracy that too in minutes.

Peace....Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I too had the similar issue and this very tool helped me resolve it that too in quick interval of time. Some related threads for the same problem are listed below:-

1. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5971506
2. http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/227269.aspx#703477